# I keep getting an error 'Cannot read property 'create' of undefined' Sequelize.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Can someone help me out? I am trying to create a user authentication with validation in my models. I keep getting an error of Cannot read property 'create' of undefined in my node.js sequelize postgres project. The error was thrown at when I use postman

model/index.js

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
// const config = require('../config/config.json')[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-2) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = sequelize["import"](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

model/user.js

```
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

'use strict';

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {

  const User = sequelize.define(
    "User",
    {
      first_name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: {
          args: false,
          msg: "Please provide a first name",
        },
      },
      last_name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: {
          args: false,
          msg: "Please provide a last name",
        },
      },
      password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: {
          args: false,
          msg: "Please provide a password",
        },
        validate: {
          isNotShort: (value) => {
            if (value.length < 8) {
              throw new Error ('Password should be at least 8 characters')
            }
          }
        }
      },
      email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        unique: {
          args: true,
          msg: "Email already exists",
        },
        allowNull: {
          args: false,
          msg: "Please provide an email address",
        },
        validate: {
          isEmail: {
            args: true,
            msg: "Please enter a valid email address",
          },
        },
      },
    },
    {}
  );


  User.beforeSave((user, options) => {
    if (user.changed('password')) {
      user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(
        user.password,
        bcrypt.genSaltSync(10),
        null
      );
    };
  });

  User.prototype.comparePassword = (passw, cb) => {
    bycrpt.compare(passw, this.password, (err, isMatch) => {
      if (err) {
        return cb(err);
      }
      cb(null, isMatch);
    });
  };

  User.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
  };
  return User;
};
```

controller/user.js

```
const express = require("express");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const passport = require("passport");
const router = express.Router();
require("../config/passport")(passport);
const keys = require('../config/keys');
const User = require('../models').User;

const signup = (req, res) => {

    if (!req.body.email || !req.body.password || !req.body.first_name || !req.body.last_name) {
        res.status(400).send({ msg: "Please pass the required information." });
  } else {
        User
        .create({
            first_name: req.body.first_name,
            last_name: req.body.last_name,
            password: req.body.password,
            email: req.body.username
        })
        .then((user) => res.status(201).send(user))
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
            res.status(400).send(error);
        });
  }
};

module.exports = {
    signup
}
```

router/user.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const usersController = require('../controllers/usersController');

router.post("/register", usersController.signup);

module.exports = router;
```

app.js

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');


var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you look at `User` variable at `User.create({` line using a breakpoint?

Comment: @Anatoly yes, i tried it but it didn't work

Comment: and what was User value? null?